# How do I use "as of now" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, time

Just to clarify, I am not a native English speaker.  I occasionally hear from other non-native English speakers the use of the phrase: "*As of now*" with the meaning of *Currently*.

Initially I did not understand what they meant and it took me a while to understand that for them saying: "*As of now it works like that*" in their mind meant "*Currently it works like that*".

I think that *As of now* is only used to indicate *From now on*. The proper phrase they should be using should be *As **is** now*. Am I wrong on this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Perhaps the people [OP](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/i-want-to-know-the-meaning-of-op) hears using ***as of*** yesterday/today/tomorrow/now/etc. misunderstand the significance of the ***as of*** part. From [Cambridge Dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/as-of-from)...

> ***as of/from*** - starting from a particular time or date:
>    *As of next month, all the airline's fares will be going up.*

Anyone with access to a suitable dictionary definition (***as is now*** the case for OP) can see that although anything which is true *as of now* is also true *currently*, there's a difference in the strong implications of each form...

> ***as of now*** = it wasn't true until very recently, but from now on it is/will be true
>    ***currently*** = it won't be true in the [near] future **AND** (possibly) *wasn't true at some point in the past*

---

Offhand, I can think of no context where ***as is now*** could directly replace ***as of now*** without some other changes to maintain "grammaticality", regardless of the intended meaning.

Comment: Ok, but there could be an everyday "mis"usage of the term in every day language that makes this more or less "accepted" in a sentence

Comment: Jim, it's always possible for someone to misuse language but I don't think this is an everyday usage. If someone used it and meant 'currently' I would never know what they meant, because I would hear 'from now on' and take it for granted that that was what they meant. I agree with FF.

Comment: I disagree that either of these implications holds: (1) *as of now* implies that it was not true formerly (at any time in the past, including recently) or that it will be true anytime in the future, (2) *currently* implies that it was not true in the past or it will not be true in the future. Why you would claim these implications, let alone call them *strong implications*, is beyond me.

Comment: @Drew: Last year, [OED offered free worldwide access](http://www.copyediting.com/free-oed-access-national-library-week-2013) for a week (I have it "free" in the UK thru my library card). During that week, if I had posted a comment here saying *"**As of now** everyone can access this definition"*, I would expect that to be understood as meaning *(...and no hurry, because the implication is this is now a **permanent** situation)*. But if I'd said *"**Currently** everyone can access this definition"*, that would imply *...not necessarily true before, and certainly will be false sometime [soon]*.

Comment: @Drew:Currently means at the moment.

Comment: @Jim: I assume the fact that you haven't actually *accepted* this answer means there's still something you don't quite understand. But your English seems quite good, and I can't easily see why you might think *as **is** now* would work in such contexts. I'm supposing you want some way of saying that something is *true **right** now*, with no particular implication as to whether it was/wasn't true in the past, or will/won't be be true in the future. Perhaps you could edit the question to clarify exactly what it is you're still not sure about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:No your answer is perfect. I was just so confused initially with this "as of now" and the fact that I hear it all the time is annoying.Hence the question

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What I disagree with is the claim that these are implied. "*Not necessarily true before* is not the same thing as *not true before*. And so on.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, *currently* means at the moment, at present, now. And your point/question is? My only comment was that the claimed implications do not hold. That something is true *as of now* does not imply that it was not true before or that it will always be true in the future. And so on - please reread what I wrote.

Comment: @Drew: Well, opinions may differ - but to me, usages like *"As of now I'm a married man"* strongly imply *...but I **wasn't,** before now*. If I wanted to imply that the condition *was* true in the past but might not be soon, I'd use something like *"As **yet** I'm unmarried"*. And if I didn't mean to imply anything at all about whether the condition was or will be different at some other time, why would I both mentioning ***now*** in the first place?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Again, *can suggest* is not the same thing as *implies*, anymore than *not necessarily true before* is the same thing as *not true before*. I don't disagree that those meanings can be suggested. I do disagree that they are implied. You can suggest something by mentioning ***now***, and you might even mean to imply that something, but you don't imply it. Not really worth discussing, but that was all I tried to say.

Comment: as of now- time to which the given piece of information applies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's OP?

Comment: @hbaromega: See link just edited in.

Answer (score 3):

This is more like a follow-up question, but I feel it is better to be posted here (rather than a separated question), for the sake of continuation and completeness.

So, to summarize the current chosen answer, and a very vivid comment gave by @FumbleFingers (which, ____, is hidden by default):

> usages like "**As of now** I'm a married man" strongly imply ...but I wasn't, before now. If I wanted to imply that the condition was true in the past but might not be soon, I'd use something like "**As yet** I'm unmarried". And if I didn't mean to imply anything at all about whether the condition was or will be different at some other time, why would I both mentioning now in the first place?

Then the implications of whether a topic was/is/will be true is represented in the row 1, 2 and 3 of the following table. So my follow-up question is, can the `#3 as yet` also be used in a positive sentence, such as "As yet I'm married"? If not, can I use `for now` i.e. "For now, I'm married"? Note that I was obviously unmarried when I was a newborn, but I've been married for several years now, can `as yet` and/or `for now` be used in such case?

```
+---+-----------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
|   | Phrase    | In the past                         | At now | In future           |
+---+-----------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| 1 | As of now | "was not true until very recently"? | TRUE   | Remains true (**)   |
| 2 | Currently | Possibly false                      | TRUE   | Probably false      |
| 3 | As yet    | "was (always?) true in the past"    | TRUE   | "might not be soon" |
| 4 | For now?  | Has been true for quite a while (*) | TRUE   | may or may not be   |
+---+-----------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+

* It might not be true at the very beginning, or it might not remain true during
  the lengthy history. What the speaker wants to say is, to his/her best knowledge,
  something has been true for a while and it is true right now, but no guarantee
  for the future. (Isn't this the most common case in daily conversation?)

** Fow what it's worth, I think "as of now" does not necessarily guarantee the topic
   would remain true for the eternity.
```

To give some context, here comes some examples. Does the implications defined in the table above apply?

1. As of now, I am a married man.
2. I'm currently married.
3. As yet I'm unmarried.
4. For now I'm married.

Or we can change to a different context, in order to NOT mess up with our spouse. :-)

1. As of now, I am living in downtown.
2. I'm currently living in downtown.
3. As yet I'm NOT living in downtown.
4. For now I'm living in downtown.

I believe situation #4 "has been true for quite a while; not sure for future" is more common, so I want to understand what is the proper way to say that. For now, I'll stick with "for now".

Answer (score 1):

As actually used in American English, constructions dating something imply or suggest change or at least the material possibility of change. It would be very odd to say that "a triangle currently has three sides" or that "a triangle has three sides as of now."

When someone says that "Y became effective as of date Z," it is implied that Y was not effective before date Z. "X is now true," X is currently true," or "X is true as of now" all imply either that X may not have been true in the past or that X may not continue to be true in the future or both.

In my opinion, however, careful speakers of American English use the "as of now" construction to emphasize the implied temporal qualification on a statement. That is, I would interpret "X is true as of now" as meaning either "but it certainly has not always been true" or "but it may well not be true forever."

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in meaning, between ‘as of now’ and ‘currently’.

‘**As of now**’ is often used to actively report current status.

Think of ‘As of now’ being like - ‘stop! Freeze the moment!’ Take a photo! And tell you what’s going on.

It also can mean that the speaker is telling you ‘the best that he knows - so far’ ie ‘as of’ or what is going on ‘now’. His or her own, ‘on the ground’ direct experience. ‘As of now’ is often used to report direct, step by step progress:

- Workman: ‘As of now, we can see the cable, and we’ll be connecting it to the router shortly’
- Reporter: ‘As of now, the suspects have been isolated in the building, by the police’
- Project Manager: ‘As of now, we’ve identified 9 problems, fixed 3, working on 3’
- Friend: ‘As of now, I’m working at Smetterley’s, but I don’t like the conditions much’

*Note how ‘as of now’ implies that working at Smetterley’s - may change.*

‘**Currently**’ is slightly more ‘ongoing’. It means more that the situation may have started earlier and has been going for a while, and may go on for longer. It often implies that the situation is more remotely controlled, not under the direct control of the speaker. Or it gives a more general and slightly longer term view, of what’s going on.

- Workman: ‘Currently, the best wifi provider is ABC’
- Reporter: ‘Currently, the police are working on a peaceful solution to the crisis’
- Project Manager: ‘Currently we have 9 problems, about 50% resolved, time to fix all, about 6 days’.
- Friend: ‘I’m looking for a new job currently, as I’m not too happy at Smetterley’s’

**Differentiation**

- I’m working at Smetterley’s = no change planned
- As of now, I’m at Smetterley’s = I am at Smetterley’s but (implied) I am actively seeking a new job now
- I’m currently at Smetterley’s = I’m considering getting a new job, but no action yet

**As is now**

You cannot use ‘as is now’ - that’s not correct. But you can use ‘as is’ to mean ‘as it is now’ or ‘without change’.

- Friend: ‘Although the sofa has been delivered in black instead of pink, we kind of like it, so we think we’ll leave it ‘as is’.
- Workman: ‘Although the pipe is protruding there, we’re going to leave it ‘as is’, as it might be dangerous to move’

‘As is’ often shows up in inverted commas when used like this - possibily because it is also a legal term, used in warranties, as well as being a part of everyday speech, as shown above.

- Goods in the auction are sold ‘as seen’ - ie ‘as is’ - no returns!

**Further useful ‘as of now’ examples:**

https://www.quora.com/What-does-as-of-now-something-mean-in-English-language

Answer (score 0):

*As of* is used to show the time or date from which something starts, "as of now" means something starts from now.

Comment: Please add a reference or citation to support your answer. Without some kind of justification, the OP and other readers have no way of knowing whether your answer is correct or you're just making things up.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the usage meaning in India, "as of now" is a more emphatic way of  restricting  our point of discussion to the present situation

Comment: Hello, M.R. Sadly, Indian English hasn't been tagged as a variant for discussion here.

Answer (score -1):

"as of now", simply means now, which still is redundant. Verbs have tenses to inform when: past; present; future. If the verb is present tense, the verb means "now" or "as of now"...neither needs to be said (or written). Example: The temperature is 57 degrees F. You don't need to say (or write) "As of now, the temperature is 57 degrees F." The verb tense takes care. The use of this redundancy, like most redundancies (close proximity comes to mind) crept in to popular use from being used by authoritative voices trying to sound important.

Comment: On the contrary, the use of terms which are logically redundant to express fine shades of meaning, including affect, is a natural and universal part of human language, In any case, your premise is false: in English, the so-called present tense does not always refer to present time.