# Usage of "As of X" when X is not a time/date

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

I've seen [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/how-do-i-use-as-of-now-correctly) and I know what "as of X" means when X is a time/date.

Is it gramatically correct to use "as of X" when X is not a time/date? For example, Is it ok to use "as of" in the following sentence?

> As of other classical facility location problems, this problem considers only location-allocation decisions.

or it is better to rewrite it to "*Like other ...*"? If both are correct, then which one is more formal, especially for a journal paper?

**Edit:**

I also found this sentence from the internet:

> The author of this, **as of other** official histories of the Second World War, has been given free access to official documents.

Maybe it's "*as well as of other ...*", but the part "*as well*" is somehow dropped?

Comment: The context of your example isn't quite clear to me, but if you say that "Like other" would be correct, then "as of" is not correct. I currently can't think of an example that uses "as of" without a time/date. "As for" can be used in some cases, but not in your example. It means "in regards to", not "like other".

Comment: Like @Flater, I think the first example is incorrect; I think "_As **in** other classical location problems..._" would be best (although "_Like other..._" could also work).

Comment: @TripeHound: Good point, I had not thought of "as in". I would suggest you post this as an answer as it seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Flater](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/75154/flater) says in the comments, I too cannot think of a case where "*As of*" (as used in the first example) works without a time/date – that doesn't guarantee there are *no* such cases, but your example isn't one of them.

"*Like other...*" could work, but I believe the best alternative would be "*As in...*":

> As **in** other classical facility location problems, this problem considers only location-allocation decisions.

Essentially it is saying, "*As [is the case] in other [similar] problems, this problem considers [a particular aspect]...*".

In the second example, the phrase is used differently, and – I believe – correctly:

> The author of this, **as of** other official histories of the Second World War, has been given free access to official documents.

Here, it is saying "*The author of [a specific work] [who is also the author of other related works] has been given...*".

---

As pointed out in a comment, there are valid uses of "*As of...*" that don't *explicitly* mention a time/date, e.g.:

> As of version 5, the application now makes coffee.
>
> As of Android Nougat, battery life is infinite.
>
> As of my last physical, I'm under doctor's orders to start exercising.

However, these all *effectively* establish a point-in-time: either through the chronology of product releases ("Version 5" and "Nougat" would have been released on specific dates) or life-events (the date of the speaker's last physical). They are thus just variants of the "*As of [time/date]...*" form.

Comment: Cromulent: "As of version 5, the application now makes coffee."  Less cromulent: "As of Android Nougat, battery life is infinite."    Probably cromulent:  "As of my last physical, I'm under doctor's orders to start exercising."

Comment: @whiskeychief Good point, but I would probably argue that – though not as specific as an explicit time/date – all those examples are establishing a "position in time" (or the chronology) of a product/life. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Agree, they all establish a specific point in time.