# How to express that a piece of information is the knowledge from a certain date?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I would like to express that a piece of information corresponds to my knowledge at a given date without implying anything on the past or future validity of the information.

Example:

> The house down the street is uninhabited.

According to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/how-do-i-use-as-of-now-correctly) I could add **(as of 15 March 2019)** at the end to say that it wasn't true recently but is true from now on. I would like to do the same without saying anything about the past or future. Adding only the date in parentheses seems a little ambiguous to me.

In case anyone is interested: The German equivalent would be **(Stand vom 15.03.19)**.

Comment: "As of March 14" doesn't (necessarily) imply a change of status at that time but simply establishes when the observation was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it explicitly clear that you aren't saying anything about other times, you can say this:

> The house down the street is uninhabited (**at least** as of 15 March 2019).

The use of *at least* qualifies the parenthetical information, indicating that you're only expressing certainty about date you specify, but leaving other times still in question.

Answer (score 1):

"At the time of writing (14 March 2019)..."

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "Since 15 March 2019, the house down the street has been uninhabited."

Comment: Or *since at least 15 March...*

Answer (score 0):

Although expressed as a statement for/from today, the most natural way for me
would be to say (based on the fact that it will be observed in the future !)

> The house down the street was uninhabited on 15 March 2019.