# What does "As Of' mean in this sentence? Were you a resident of (What ever state or province) as of December 31, 2021 for income tax purposes?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Filling out a government form and I'm stumped by this question and second-guessing myself.

> Were you a resident of (whatever state or province) as of December 31, 2021 for income tax purposes?  Yes or No?

Comment: What guesses have you made?

Comment: Look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/how-do-i-use-as-of-now-correctly

Comment: In the first listed duplicate above, I can only recommend the answer giving an overview of how various dictionaries define the term 'as of'. It is ill-defined (has conflicting senses). John V, in a comment, gives two examples showing different senses:  1) As of today, only three survivors have been found. 2) As of today, all passengers must check their luggage before boarding the plane. // Here, context doesn't disambiguate.

Comment: In this case, you look only at that date and say you were or weren't X (on that very date).

Comment: The evaluation of residence for state tax purposes is made on (as of) the date specified and is, in many states, six months during the calendar year, or more precisely 180 days. The tax form should have instructions. There are exceptions, e.g., for caring for a family member. Ask on the legal forum.